# How to implement Metronic Admin theme in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, themes

I'd purchased this Metronic Theme and I'm trying to implement it in VS 2013 ASP.NET MVC. I did tried but all went wrong, is there any one who can guide me with this

Comment: Did you include all of the themes contents (css, js, images) properly with bundling?

Comment: Yes I did, moved all assets to the project, when I tried to add layout to the _layout partial view every thng went wrong and project stop working at all

Comment: Your `_Layout` file has a few Razor Engine things in it that need to be there, namely `@RenderBody()` . If you just copy and pasted everything from your theme file over the existing `_Layout` code, then it would break. You need to copy and paste select parts from your theme into the `_Layout` file to properly integrate your template.

Comment: Yes I know that I didn't remove the @renderBODY() from the layout I paced every thing one by one and in the end got nothing

Comment: I was looking for any tutorial or video where some one has done that but couldn't find any thing on that

Comment: Implementing an html theme isn't very complicated so I doubt you will find many tutorials on that particular subject.  Without seeing your code, it's hard to help. If you posted the code in your `_Layout` file, we could help troubleshoot better.

Comment: you are right but Its a DAMN huge theme if you know about it, rich with lot of stuff:: Thank you any ways

Comment: This post I wrote may help you: http://cpratt.co/how-to-change-the-default-asp-net-mvc-themet/

Answer (score 6):

Just put blank page content to _Layout.cshtml.

For example i copied Assets to under Content folder so i changed link like that:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@*@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")*@

<!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
<!-- BEGIN THEME STYLES -->
<link href="~/Content/assets/global/css/components.css" id="style_components" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/assets/global/css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/assets/admin/layout/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link id="style_color" href="~/Content/assets/admin/layout/css/themes/darkblue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/assets/admin/layout/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- END THEME STYLES -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

and javascripts are below the page (just before closing body tag):

```
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)*@

<!-- BEGIN JAVASCRIPTS(Load javascripts at bottom, this will reduce page load time) -->
<!-- BEGIN CORE PLUGINS -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="../../assets/global/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/global/plugins/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- IMPORTANT! Load jquery-ui.min.js before bootstrap.min.js to fix bootstrap tooltip conflict with jquery ui tooltip -->
<script src="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/jquery.cokie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->
<script src="~/Content/assets/global/scripts/metronic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/assets/admin/layout/scripts/layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/assets/admin/layout/scripts/quick-sidebar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/assets/admin/layout/scripts/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        Metronic.init(); // init metronic core components
        Layout.init(); // init current layout
        QuickSidebar.init(); // init quick sidebar
        Demo.init(); // init demo features
    });
</script>
<!-- END JAVASCRIPTS -->
```

and to show views content in layout put RenderBody here:

```
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE CONTENT-->
```

Answer (score -3):

You can check http://www.aspnetzero.com/

It's an ASP.NET Startup project which uses Metronic as UI theme.
It's not a simple startup template but also a strong architecture and framework.